# How can I locate which LOB column in ORACLE view creation is causing LOB error?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create view in an Oracle database which few references to remote tables with DB Links and getting the below error:

> Error report - ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
> 22992. 00000 -  "cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables"
> *Cause:    A remote LOB column cannot be referenced.
> *Action:   Remove references to LOBs in remote tables.

Went through all referenced columns in the view, none of them are LOBs.
Is there any way I can understand which LOB is the error referring to?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you are selecting `*` somewhere in the view definition and that includes a LOB...

Comment: What are the datatypes of all the columns you are pulling?

Answer (score 0):

To locate the CLOB column just using your query you could try it like here:

```sql
-- Query that raises the error
SELECT  MENU_ID, 
        A_DATE, 
        SOAP_RESPONSE "SOAP"
FROM    YOUR_TABLE@remote_db
SQL Error: ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
--  Try select just one column to test the query
SELECT  MENU_ID
FROM    YOUR_TABLE@remote_db

MENU_ID            
--------------------
10_10                
10_20                
60_20             
--
--  If it works add another
SELECT  MENU_ID, A_DATE
FROM    YOUR_TABLE@remote_db

MENU_ID              A_DATE   
-------------------- ---------
10_10                04-JUL-22 
10_20                01-JUL-22 
60_20                Null                         

--
--  Keep adding columns till you get the same error message
SELECT  MENU_ID, A_DATE, SOAP_RESPONSE
FROM    YOUR_TABLE@remote_db
--
SQL Error: ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks d r , I found that what is not working is a column with LISTAGG. It is not using any LOB column but maybe it itself is being define as LOB by the system?

LISTAGG (ca.parent_id, ', ')
             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ca.parent_id)
             OVER (PARTITION BY EG_TRX.TRX_KEY )
              FROM cm.alerts al INNER JOIN cm.acm_relations ca
             ON ca.child_id = AL.ALERT_ID) AS cases_per_evidence,